# jquery when click on link, move position to textarea

Tags: jquery

Whenever you press comment on facebook, u can see the page move to textarea in comment box.

how do i achieve that? focus? any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
element.onclick = function() {
   window.scrollTo( textarea.offsetLeft, textarea.offsetTop );
   textarea.focus();
};
```